# I am using File History in Windows 8.1 (x64), I see only two folders in the File History folder

Tags: windows-8

Others seems to see many other folders. I see only two folders Configuration and Data. And Data has two subfolders C (probably the C:) and $F. Is there more documentation somewhere?

It has been working for more than a few hours and File History is about 25GB and I am not sure if it is going to finish, and if so When?

Windows 10 update started in the mean time and both programs are running.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal.

```
[pythonnut@pro /me/sf_X/Py/ <2>]% tree -L 3
.
├── Configuration
│   ├── Catalog1.edb
│   ├── Catalog2.edb
│   ├── Config1.xml
│   └── Config2.xml
└── Data
    ├── C
    │   └── Users
    └── $OF
        ├── 1492
        ├── 1513
        ├── 1531
        ├── 1669
        ├── 1735
        ├── 1798
        ├── 1810
        ├── 1828
        ├── 1851
        ├── 1950
        └── 2377

16 directories, 4 files
```

(please pardon the usage of Linux for a Windows question)

As you can see `Configuration/Data/C/Users` leads to your `C:/Users` folder. This is where the files are stored, and if all is well, your backups are safely kept.